# Need help figuring out how to save 1500 pictures between 2 iPhones and and iPad while traveling

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud, photos, photo-stream

I need help.  I have been traveling for 5 months and have 2 iPhones with me as well as my iPad.  One of my iPhones is a 4, this is my work phone.  I have approximately 1500 pictures on this phone that I would like to be able to save before I turn my phone back into my company. (it will then be reset to factory settings). So far I have not been able to figure out how to successfully place my pictures in the iCloud so that I can access them from my personal iPhone 5 or my iPad.  I am in a very remote area and do not have a desktop or another computer with me.  Also, the wifi is often patchy.
Do I create a photo stream on the work phone?  Do I need to email myself each and every picture?
I have about a month and 1/2 more of this trip and my work phone is telling me that I am out of storage and unable to take anymore pictures. 
Help..if you can.
thanks
A

Comment: Due to compression, each picture could vary in size substantially and x1000 pictures that can make a big difference in the total amount of storage. If you go to settings app, how much space does the camera roll actually take?

Answer (score 1):

For part of your solution you could try [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com) to upload the files for later retrieval.

Download the [app](https://www.dropbox.com/mobile) on you iPhone 4 and setup an account.

To upload your images follow the instructions [here (with visual aids)](https://www.dropbox.com/help/84/en#). Which are:

- First navigate to the location within your Dropbox where you'd like
  to put the photos. Then do the following:
- Tap the ellipsis (...) icon at the top right of the screen to get a
  drop-down menu.
- Tap Upload (+) from the menu.

(Optional: To put the photos in a new folder, tap Create Folder from the menu first before uploading.)

- Tap the ellipsis icon to get a drop-down menu.
- Select the album you'd like to upload photos from.
- Select the photos and videos you want to upload.
- Tap the Upload button at the top of the screen.

---

You could install the dropbox app on your personal iPhone login and the download the images from dropbox. But oddly dropbox do not do a multiple download to the iPhone photo library only single. ( pain)

It is possible to use third party app and logging into your dropbox account through it would allow you to do multiple downloads

---

Also dropbox have a new auto upload which may help you when you take new photos.

> The Dropbox mobile app gives you different ways to upload files from
>   your phone or tablet to your Dropbox account. Once files are uploaded,
>   they will sync with Dropbox on your computer and all your other
>   devices.
>
> Upload photos and videos automatically
>
> Dropbox can automatically upload photos and videos taken from your
>   iPhone. This feature is called Camera Upload, and you can turn it on
>   when you first install the app or by going to the app's settings. You
>   can also choose whether to allow uploading when your device is
>   connected to a cellular network.

---

Keep in mind you get about 2GB+  free.

1500 images may that up most of that space. You can see how much by looking at the usage settings on iPhone ( amount will include video sizes)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to back up your work phone to iCloud. You might have to pay for fast wifi if yours is too slow and also turn off backing up all items except photos initially.

Later on Make complete and current backup of one of your personal devices again using iCloud.

Note:1, Backing up two devices to iCloud may mean you run out of  your free 5 GB allotment and may not be able to do so without buying more storage or deleting data to complete the backup/s.

Note: 2, Also if your volume of data makes bandwidth a problem for transferring them, renting or borrowing a computer to move the files over to USB storage may be far more time efficient and save the cost of iCloud storage if you can't fit everything in your free 5 GB allotment.

You can also backup directly through iTunes which would mean you do not have to worry about space in iCloud with both the backups and can do the work-phone backup via iCloud while still away and the personal-phone backup via a iTunes when you get back.

Once both phone have been backed up though either means and you haven't managed to do note 2.

Restore the work-phone backup from iCloud to that personal-device (remember the iOS version of the work phone)

Use a computer to archive the photos from the newly restored temp device.

Then restore the personal-device's current backup back to the temp device once again making it the personal device.

At that point, you can turn in the work phone.
You should now also be able to delete the old work-phone backup from iCloud.

The least practical method would be to beam the files using iPhoto or just airdrop them from the photos app, but I can't imagine doing that for 250 photos let alone 1.5k times. Even grouping multiple photos (5 might be the limit) to transfer a group isn't efficient use of time.